# How to make a scatter plot of based on the value of 'type' column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scatter-plot

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
type    date     count      CLASS  
  A      jan    456     0 
  A      feb    121     1 
  A      mar    333     1
  B      apr    123     1   
  B      may    123     1
  C      jun    189     1
  C      jul    789     1
```

I would like to create a scatter plot of the counts of type 'A' over time (date), so I would need to use the type, date, and count columns.

I would like to do something like this, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the counts column?

```
group = df.groupby('Type' == 'A')

df.plot.scatter(x = 'Year_Month', y = group)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I also get a key error when I try this ^

Basically, the scatter plot should plot the counts of type A over time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[df['type']=='A'].plot.scatter('date', 'count')
```

Since you only want the data where type is `A` you don't need a groupby here.